# mockImplementation() still calling the original functionality of the method

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Supposed I have a code

```
const SomeEmailModule = require('SomeEmailModule')
const emailModule = new SomeEmailModule()


async function sendEmail(htmlBody) {
    await emailModule.send(htmlBody)
    return htmlBody
}
```

and when I used it on test using jest

```
const SomeEmailModule = require('SomeEmailModule')

it('can test', async () => {

    const emailModule = new SomeEmailModule()
    jest.spyOn(emailModule, 'send').mockImplementation()
    ......some code
)
```

the module doesn't actually mock the method `send` it stills do the original functionality of the method any idea why it happened?

---

Okay after some testing

```
const mockSend = jest.fn()
SomeEmailModule.prototype.send = mockSend
```

this solution works however I want to know how this one works while the other one doesn't

---

this one also works

```
const mockSend = jest.spyOne(SomeEmailModule.prototype, 'send').mockImplementation()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `emailModule` instance of the `SomeEmailModule` class in your test case is different from the one in the file under test.

```js
jest.spyOn(emailModule, 'send').mockImplementation();
```

You just install a spy on the `emailModule` instance created in the test case, but the `emailModule` instance in the file under test is not spied.

But installing spy on `SomeEmailModule.prototype.send()` will work, because all instances share the same prototype.